# Creation of /proc/stat 

Tags: boot, kernel, cpu, proc

Which function of the kernel creates and writes the information for /proc/stat. In this, would like to know when kernel gets the cpu information(recognises number of cpus).

**If possible can anyone explain when exactly kernel knows(reads) cpu count at boot time?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check out show_stat() in fs/proc/stat.c